# Google Sheets event "onEdit"

Tags: events, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

There was a problem with the event "onEdit" (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). If you start editing a cell and enter the value that was in it, the event will not work. Tell me how can I handle this situation when the cell is open for editing, but the value in it is not changed?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Kindly tag macro related questions to [tag:google-apps-script]  in the future. We use [tag:google-sheets-macros] exclusively for recorded macros.

Comment: @TheMaster Thx for the quick info. Makes sense.

Comment: Sheets UI doesn't save after you click enter if the value remains the same, so the onEdit trigger won't run. Could you explain what's the purpose of this? And please provide an example spreadsheet for better understanding. May be I can give you a workaround for your case.

Comment: I want to make an increasing amount in one cell, as is done here with the macros in Excel: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P_4GBl5NTPyE-R0TyOWrx7lkgA5RGHhU (Open with Excel)

Answer (score 0):

Excel and Google Sheets have different behaviors, in this case, you can't replicate Excel's behavior on Sheets because Sheets doesn't update/save a file if you enter to a cell and after editing the cell (hitting enter) the value remains the same as before, so the onEdit trigger won't run.